# EC2 check in Auto Scaling group

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have an ASG with min=2, max=4 configuration. In the boot up script of each EC2, I have a series of yum install and starting of 2 spring boot files. Now, when th e load increases and ASG spins up a new EC2 instance, it will perform all these in the boot up script.

Could anybody suggest a good method to validate whether all these yum installs have been successful and also whether the 2 spring boot files are running currently. If there is any problem with these, I dont want the EC2 instance to be attached to ELB.

Answer (score 0):

I used cfn-signal to send information back to Cloudformation after performing my application and infrastructure level checks

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html